# VS Code does not detect Conda packages when launched without the Anaconda Launcher?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

VS Code is unable to detect the torch package that I installed exclusively in one of the Conda environments. If I launch VS Code through Anaconda Launcher, however, then it detects torch and everything works fine.

I have done many things in order to make the Conda environment work on VS Code PowerShell terminal, and so far Conda is getting activated on VS Code terminal properly regardless of whether I launch it with or without the Anaconda Launcher. But when trying to run the the program via Code Runner, it always shows the error that the torch module is not found.

But doing the same thing in terminal or launching VS Code through Anaconda launcher works just fine.

I don't know what to do, it is so annoying. I really wanted to work with Python on VS Code as it looks neat and clean compared to other editors and also since it is also light and fast. Unfortunately, making Conda work on VS Code is a nightmare, and it seems like the only way to make it work is through launching it via Anaconda Launcher, but opening Anaconda Launcher takes too much time compared to VS Code -_-

Please help assist with launching the code through VS Code.

Comment: Are you on windows, linux, or Mac?

Comment: @BallpointBen Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

It's because conda activation sets various environment variables which are required for a conda environment to function appropriately. And I suspect the Code Runner extension simply doesn't understand the concept of a conda environment, and so it isn't doing any activating which makes the import search fail.

You can try executing code directly through the Python extension instead of Code Runner to see if that works better for you.

Comment: So the problem is with Code Runner I see. But nevermind, I was able to make it work by installing pytorch, torchvision via pip. That way code runner is able to give the output as expected.